# How to make shape visible based on calculation in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint quiz which calculates a score. If the score is above 80% I would like a button(shape with name "PrintCert") to become visible so the user may print a certificate. Currently the button is always visible. Here is the code that I've tried with no success. (The first and last part of the code updates labels.)

```
Sub showresult()
Percentage.Caption = Int((CA.Caption) * 100 /     (TQ.Caption)) & "%"
With ActivePresentation.Slides(37)
If ((CA.Caption) * 100 / (TQ.Caption)) > 79.9 Then
.Shapes("PrintCert").Visible = True
Else
.Shapes("PrintCert").Visible = False
End If
End With
SlideLayout41.PercentageCertificate.Caption = Percentage.Caption
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest thing might be to add a new first slide with a "Start the show" action button that users click to begin the presentation.  You'd apply a Run Macro action setting to the button and have it run a macro something like this:

```
Sub StartShow()

    ' set your button shapes to be invisible
    With SlideShowWindows(1).Presentation.Slides(37)
        .Shapes("PrintCert").Visible = False
    End With
    ' etc, for any other shapes you want to have
    ' hidden to start with

    ' go to the actual first slide
    SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide (2)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is actually the second to last slide in the presentation. Once the user reaches the slide their score is calculated and displayed. If the score is 80% or above they have passed and the button should appear. Currently, anyone can press the button and get a certificate (which is on the next slide.) Do you know how I can make the button visible if the score is 80 or above?

Comment: Use the same general technique: add a slide prior to the one with the final score/print certificate button, include some text like "You're finished, click below to see your results" and add a shape/button with a Run Macro action setting, the macro moves them to the next slide and makes the print button visible or not depending on their score. OR you could just leave a visible "Print" button there all the time, and have it invoke code that prints or tells them their score isn't high enough.

Comment: Ok, perhaps I'm not being clear enough with my question. I already have a button like you suggest but I don't know how to make the macro which decides if the score is high enough to trigger visibility of the print button. My code shown above doesn't work. What I need is the code to determine if the user scored 80% or not and then make the button visible or not. I'm assuming its an if/then statement but everything I've tried will not work.

Comment: You can declare a variable as Static to hold the number of correct answers, e.g. Static RightAnswers as Long. Set it to zero as part of the code on the first slide that we've already discussed, then increment it for every correct answer. Use that vs the total number of answers in the quiz to calculate the score, then use essentially the same If/Then logic you've already written to make the button visible or not.  If problems, edit your existing post to match the current version of code you have so we're looking at the same thing.